# How can I get my form input fields to show when using Spring Boot with Spring MVC as the templating engine?

Tags: spring-boot, forms, spring-mvc

So I have a form created with Spring MVC tags and it looks like this

```
<form:form action="/languages" method="post" modelAttribute="language">
    <p>
        <form:label path="name">Name</form:label>
        <form:errors path="name"/>
        <form:input type="text" path="name"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <form:label path="creator">Creator</form:label>
        <form:errors path="creator"/>
        <form:input type="text" path="creator"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <form:label path="currentVersion">Version</form:label>
        <form:errors path="currentVersion"/>
        <form:input type="number" path="currentVersion"/>
    </p>
  
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

The problem is that it is only showing the labels for the form and not the input where a user can enter things. Am I missing something here? I'm pretty new to Spring boot and Spring MVC tags so im not sure what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I forgot to add

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

to the jsp file.